# Why did NothingToInstall.com stop redirecting to WebApps?

Tags: bug, status-completed

It used to be the case that [Nothingtoinstall Gets Directed to WebApps.StackExchange.com](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/632/) similar to how arqade.com gets redirected to Gaming.SE, etc.

But the redirect [no longer works](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://nothingtoinstall.com), meaning that any [external links](http://www.marco.org/2010/10/01/nothing-to-install-launched) to the old name are broken.

SE still owns the domain, and the URLs http://www.nothingtoinstall.com and http://meta.nothingtoinstall.com correctly redirect to Web Applications. But http://nothingtoinstall.com,  the URL actually used when the site first launched, does not.

Comment: I will leave this as a bug report for now, but does not having the redirect in place actually break anything?

Comment: It breaks any external links to the old domain, an example of which is in my post.

Comment: Fair enough. I hadn't followed the link, sorry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That *should* be working. Or, at least, we didn't intentionally turn it off, so you're quite right that this is a bug.

We'll fix up the meta.nothingtoinstall redirect to point to Web Apps Meta, but we'll need to contact the domain registrar to see what's going on with http://nothingtoinstall.com and get that going again.

**Update:** Changes have been made, might take a bit to propagate across [the series of tubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_of_tubes).

Comment: Any idea what caused it to be down for those five months? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes. Literally nobody cares about these domain redirects so we never noticed that moving to another registrar introduced a problem.

Answer (score 10):

SE Inc thought it was a horrible name even though one of their staff came up with it. The redirect stayed initially I'm guessing to preserve the initial traffic flow that came when Web apps was launched (WA was the first 2.0 SE site).

I'm guessing someone in SE staff has decided the redirect no longer needs to be there.

The difference between Arqade and us is that we were never blessed with a vanity name officially.